# Overriding object attribute access

Tags: ruby

I was wondering if it's possible to make it so that if I had something like

```
class Test

  attr_reader :access_times
  def initialize
    @access_times = 0
  end

  def get_two
    2
  end

  ...
end

t = Test.new
```

That any access to `t` would run a particular piece of code before actually running the method?

For example, if I suddenly decided to say `t.get_two`, the fact that I used the `.` syntax would increment `@access_times` by 1. Or perhaps I made a check `t.is_a?(Test)`, it would also increment `@access_times` by 1. Accessing any methods or attributes inherited by `Test` would also increment the variable by 1.

Basically I want to add some stuff to the `.` syntax if possible.

I am not asking whether this is good or bad code, just whether it's possible and how it would be done. I wouldn't normally use it since I could just add the increment logic to every method manually and replace all direct instance variable accessing with methods (even things like `is_a?` and other things inherited from `Object`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a pretty hardcore-version would be to use `set_trace_func`: http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/set_trace_func

this allows you to subscribe to all the ruby events fired throughout your program, which can be a ton of calls...

i don't think that there is a build-in hook for registering to arbitrary method-calls. you could implement something with method-missing, method-chaining or delegation, but that would depend on your requirments.

Comment: I used method-missing as a temporary solution until I find a better way to do it. Will look into what method-chaining and delegation are about.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need everything to be standalone, a suggestion would just be to extend [`ActiveModel::Callbacks`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html). Simply extend the class and you'll have all of the functionality of a before_filter without requiring all of the other Rails stuff.

Comment: this would only work for active-model livecycle callbacks, wouldn't it?

Comment: I would like it to be standalone, but thanks for the suggestion. I'm not working with Rails for this though so I'm not sure if that particular module is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround according to your description.  Basically it will incremental @access_times for each of the instance method, and the method also does what it does before.

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :access_times

  def initialize
    @access_times = 0
  end

  def get_two
    2
  end
end

class Test
  @@im = instance_methods

  @@im.each do |m|
    class_eval <<-END
      alias temporary #{m}
    END

    define_method(m) do |*args, &block|
      @access_times += 1
      temporary(*args, &block)
    end
  end

  undef :temporary
end

Test.new.get_two # => @access_times += 1 and original get_two is called: 2
```

While this piece of code doesn't work as expected, I'll have a look at it later.  Thanks.